# Call different function based on a boolean

Tags: c#

I have a boolean in my function that decide what function to call. Both of the function that are beying called giving back an Array.

Now in my eyes `Hex[] areaHexes` does exists but the compiler does not compile because it thinks its not set ( does not exists ).

How do I call one of both function properly based on what value `bool semiRandom` has?

```
void ElevateArea(int q, int r, int range, bool semiRandom = false, float centerHeight = 1f)
{
    Hex centerHex = GetHexAt(q, r);

    if (semiRandom) 
    { 
        Hex[] areaHexes = GetSemiRandomHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range);
    } 
    else
    {
        Hex[] areaHexes = GetHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range);
    }

    foreach (Hex h in areaHexes)
    {
        //if (h.Elevation < 0)
            // h.Elevation =  0;

        h.Elevation += 0.5f * Mathf.Lerp(1f, 0.25f, Hex.Distance(centerHex, h ) / range);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `areaHexes` is being declared locally within your `if-else` blocks, it's not visible outside of the scope of those blocks. Declare it outside: `Hex[] areaHexes;` then `if (semiRandom) { areaHexes = ... } ...` etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that you are currently declaring two local variables called `areaHexes`, each of which has a scope which is just the block they're declared in - so neither of them is in scope when you try to use them.

Brandon's answer (declaring the variable outside the `if` statement and then assigning to it from different places) will work fine - `areaHexes` is now in scope when you use it later. However, you can do it more simply with a conditional ?: operator:

```
Hex[] areaHexes = semiRandom
    ? GetSemiRandomHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range)
    : GetHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range);
```

Comment: Do this instead. It looks way more beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

Your `areaHexes` is being declared locally within your `if-else` blocks, it's not visible outside of the scope of those blocks. You have two different local `areaHexes` variables:

```
if (semiRandom) 
{
    // This definition of areaHexes is visible only within these { }
    //   and is not the same as the one in the else block below
    Hex[] areaHexes = GetSemiRandomHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range);
} 
else
{
    // This definition of areaHexes is visible only within these { }
    //   and is not the same one as the one above
    Hex[] areaHexes = GetHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range);
}
```

Declare it outside:

```
Hex[] areaHexes;

if (semiRandom) { 
    areaHexes = GetSemiRandomHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range);
}
else {
    areaHexes = GetHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range);
}
```

Or, use the tertiary `?:` operator Jon showed.

You should look up *variable scope rules* for C#.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your array before your condition, like so:

```
Hex[] areaHexes;

if (semiRandom) 
{ 
    areaHexes = GetSemiRandomHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range);
} 
else
{
    areaHexes = GetHexesWithinRangeOf(centerHex, range);
}
```